# AWS RDS bidirectional replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, disaster-recovery

I'm researching about AWS RDS bidirectional replication. I know that RDS has the read replica, but I need the bidirectional replication for disaster recovery.
Would anyone have the experience with this before? I'm very appreciated for your help.

Comment: Do you mean synchronous replication. It should work if you have multi-az enabled.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I used MySQL.

Comment: @dev: I already have Multi-AZ enabled. Now I would like to have Multi-Region.

Answer (score 1):

AWS RDS does have multi master capability with Aurora. See documentation below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html

It supports replication across multiple master across multiple AZ. This is for a region only. Since you mentioned disaster recovery, it might not satisfy your requirement but you can evaluate it to decide as per your requirements.

See the blog post below which talks about replication architecture of multi master Auora

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-highly-available-mysql-applications-using-amazon-aurora-mmsr/

For cross region, you can use Auora Global database but that supports only 1 writer instance.

Answer (score 1):

What db engine are you using in RDS? is that mysql, pgsql , sql server or oracle? Aurora multi-master only supports MySQL, and even multi-master we are talking about both master in same AWS region, which may not satisfy your requirement of "DR". Why do you need bidirectional in first place? If the writes from "master A" and "master B" are isolated, i.e. A and B did not update same portion of same table at the same time, then you may consider to use AWS DMS bi-directional replication to setup a DR db for your primary DB, but notice that AWS DMS bi-directional replication is not a multi-master db solution, it won't handle any data conflict / inconsistency if primary and replica db update same rows. For detail please refer to AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html#CHAP_Task.CDC.Bidirectional